# Using pure CSS, make a div centered until it runs into sidebar from resizing the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a website with a single fixed-width centered column and an additional fixed-width sidebar that is position: fixed on the left. When the window is large, this works perfectly, but when I resize the window, they begin to overlap when there's plenty of room left on the right side of the window. For example:

[image]

I'd like the center div to be positioned in the center *until it runs into the sidebar*, at which point I'd like it to have a more fluid responsive design, where the sidebar starts to push the div to the right as you resize the window. For example:

[image]

The only solution I'm aware of is something like this (using the jQuery resize event and adding a class to the center column when the window resizes small enough):

```js
var SMALL_WINDOW_SIZE = 560;

function checkWindowSize() {
  var $content = $("#content");
  if ($(this).width() < SMALL_WINDOW_SIZE && !$content.hasClass("smallWindow")) {
    $content.addClass("smallWindow");
  } else if ($(this).width() >= SMALL_WINDOW_SIZE && $content.hasClass("smallWindow")) {
    $content.removeClass("smallWindow");
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  checkWindowSize();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  checkWindowSize();
});
```

```css
#sidebar {
  background: orange;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
#content {
  background: blue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.smallWindow {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 120px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='sidebar'></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

I can't help but feel there should be a pure CSS solution or one that uses less or more elegant JavaScript. Is there such a thing?

Comment: You know at what viewport width the overlap will start to occur, so use media queries to apply different formatting in that case.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks! I was unaware of CSS media queries for some reason. Seems like something I should have picked up on from somewhere by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't by any means the best way of achieving the desired effect with CSS, but it's the methodology behind using CSS media queries to adapt layout that I want to convey.

Obviously if this meets your needs, you'll want to adjust the numbers/widths to suit your case.

```css
*, :before, :after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}

.sidebar, .main {
  padding: 20px
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  background: goldenrod;
  color: white;
  height: 50vh;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 220px;
  background: mediumblue;
  color: white;
  height: 200vh;
}


@media (min-width: 1050px){
  .main{
    margin: 0 220px 0 220px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    Sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    Main
  </div>
  </div>
```

[**» JSBin**](http://output.jsbin.com/vilexivazi)